# What's the difference HLS(http live stream) and DSS(darwin streaming server)

Tags: http-live-streaming, broadcast, darwin

I'm beginner developer.
And I don't speak engilsh very well. sorry

I want to broadcast live video from iPhone camera like iphone video call.
In this case, which do I choice better, hls or dss.
so, what's the functional difference HLS and DSS.
Can hls broadcast live video from iphone camera to another iphone?

Answer (score 0):

Darwin Streaming Server is for RTSP streaming. HLS is a streaming technology based on using HTTP server for hosting the content.

iPhone to iPhone video isn't well served by either technology. It's possible to use an iPhone camera to capture video, upload it to a server, package it for HLS and serve it to the client viewers. This is very high latency (around 10-30 seconds), so it's likely not suitable for you.

If you want 1-to-1 messaging, you're probably better off using a real-time system like RTP, which is what's used by FaceTime and video calling programs.